# How does a http proxy server proxy https requests?

Tags: proxy, https, tunneling

Searching through the web, I still don't quite understand how a proxy server proxies HTTPS. I read that an HTTP proxy knows the port number and SNI of a CONNECT request, but if the proxy itself is running on 443 with SSL, then the client with have to negotiate SSL with the proxy server first then send proxy requests. Does that mean the connection between the original client/server is encrypted twice, i.e. TLS over TLS?

Comment: It helped me, so I recommend reading mitmproxy [docs](https://docs.mitmproxy.org/stable/concepts-howmitmproxyworks/) to understand how it works.